# Are hyperparameters trained when k-fold cross validation is applied

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I just started working with k fold CV and am a little bit confused about the topic mentioned above. How are my hyperparameters tuned if I use a k fold approach to train my model. What I read so far is that the validation dataset isn't necessary anymore. My understanding about the common split is, that the train dataset mainly adresses the adjustment of the weights. Thus, the validation dataset is used to adjust the hyperparameters to avoid overfitting.

Since my tensorflow fit function only receives a training dataset, when CV is used, then there is no adjustment of hyperparameters and e.g. my Adam-optimizer isn't that useful. Or does the fit-routine change if there is no validation dataset set?

I have to be wrong so thanks for your help!